# how to get data from telegram bot with google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

how to get the data from the telegram bot with google app script.

I have this script that extracts the last messages that I send to the bot from my cell phone. These messages are placed on the right of the screen.

Now I also send text to the bot from the script, and the text is placed on the left of the screen.

The question is how do I get the data on the left? Specifically, I need to get the data on the left, which is several photos.

is it possible to get them? I have tried in many ways and I have not been able to get the data that is put on the left of the screen.

```
    function obtenerUltimosMensajes() {
  var token = TELEGRAM_TOKEN; // Reemplazar con el token de acceso de tu bot de Telegram
  
  var apiUrl = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + token + '/getUpdates?limit=5';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl);
  var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  
  if (jsonResponse.ok) {
    var resultado = jsonResponse.result;
    if (resultado.length > 0) {
      var mensajes = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < resultado.length; i++) {
        var mensaje = resultado[i].message;
        var texto = mensaje.text;
        mensajes.push(texto);
      }
      Logger.log(mensajes);
    } else {
      Logger.log('No se encontraron mensajes en el bot');
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('Error al obtener mensajes: ' + jsonResponse.description);
  }
}
```